# SQL query with CASE WHEN by dbgetQuery does not work

Tags: sql, r, dbi, sparklyr

I have a problem: I tested CASE WHEN SQL query in R, but I obtained an error. Could you, please propose a solution?

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(gapminder)
spark_conn <- spark_connect(master = "local")
data("gapminder")
copy_to(spark_conn, gapminder)
src_tbls(spark_conn)

#The query gave an error
DBI::dbGetQuery(spark_conn, "
                SELECT *
                CASE WHEN pop > 100000000 THEN 'Biggy'
                WHEN pop < 10000000 THEN 'Small'
                ELSE 'Medium' END
                AS pop_category
                FROM gapminder 
                WHERE year = 1957
                ")


Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'WHEN' expecting <EOF>(line 3, pos 21)

== SQL ==

                SELECT *
                CASE WHEN pop > 10000000 THEN 'Biggy'
---------------------^^^
                WHEN pop < 10000000 THEN 'Small'
                ELSE 'Medium' END
                AS pop_category
                FROM gapminder
```

Comment: You are missing a comma before `CASE`. Also, `SELECT *`  possibly should be `SELECT pop_category.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing comma `,` after `*`. just add comma after it and your query should work fine

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN pop > 100000000 THEN 'Biggy'
    WHEN pop < 10000000 THEN 'Small'
    ELSE 'Medium' END
    AS pop_category
FROM gapminder 
WHERE year = 1957
```

Comment: I confirm, It works fine